# Cypress: Catch exception message boxes in application at any time

Tags: cypress

I have some cypress tests where there can appear at any time a message box with an incident message. Usually after a click, but because of the async loading not always just after.

If the incident does not affect the next step in the test, the test just goes on without failing.
Ideally, I would like to catch at all times such message boxes and prevent just hopping over it without handling it properly.

How would I build such an listener who checks after, let's say, after every "cy.XX" event?

[image]

- after each click is not working, because I don't know if such a message box appears. So waiting for a certain amount of time, slows down the tests.

Message Box example:

```
<div class="MuiBox-root css-k008qs" data-e2e-notification-message="">
<div data-e2e-notification-message-severity="ERROR">etc etc.
<span>Something went wrong ....</span></div></div>
```

Comment: Letting exception messages slip into production without addressing it, could be a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, that is why we want to catch it, because it can happen sometimes during dev.